# Pytorch Inner Product of 3D tensor with 1D Tensor to generate 2D Tensor

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Operation : I have pytorch tensor `A` of dimension `[n x m x c]` and `B` of dimension `[1 x 1 x c]`. I want to take inner product of each of `1 x 1 x c` vector from `A` with `B` and hence generate a tensor `C` of dimension `[n x m]`.

Inside forward function of my network at a specific step I receive tensor of dimension `[N, channels, Height, Width]` where N is number of images, channels is number of channels in the feature map, and height and width are of the current feature map. I also have an `[N x channels]` feature map from some other subnetwork. In the next step I want to carry out the above mentioned operation.

Can somebody explain the best way and functions available in pytorch to achieve such step.

I am new to pytorch and was unable to find a proper way. Tensorflow supports NHWC format but I think pytorch doesn't, so one of the way is to reshape it to `[N, Height, Width, channels]` and then iterate like :

```
# if img is reshaped to [N, H, W, C]
img
# tensor of dimension [N, C]
aud

ans = torch.empty(N, H, W, dtype=torch.double)

for batches in range(img.shape[0]):
    for i in range(img.shape[1]):
        for j in range(img.shape[2]):
            ans[batches][i][j] = torch.dot(img[batches][i][j], aud[batches])
```

Any other cleaner API ?

PS : This step is required in DeepMind's paper "Object That Sound" for sound localization step.

Comment: Just multiply your [n x m x c] with B on the last axis and sum last axis afterwards, effectively yielding [n x m].

Comment: Carrying out the standalone operation is easy but the main problem is when I have tensor in form of [N, C, H, W] and [N, C] inside the forward step.

Comment: PyTorch allows you to permute indices, remember to use contiguous after this operation.

Comment: I will check torch.permute, looks like it can help in reshaping, can you explain more about "contiguous" thing ?

Comment: Permutation creates a view of Tensor. If you put it inside neural network, allocated memory will not be accessed in contiguous manner (e.g. you will jump to separated memory addresses) and operations will be much slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a one-liner

```
 ans = torch.einsum('nhwc,nc->nhw', img, aud)
```

The API of [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.einsum) can be difficult to grasp if you haven't had any experience with it before, but it's extremely powerful and generalizes a great deal of liner algebra operations (transpositions, matrix multiplications and traces).

```
import torch

N, H, W, C = 10, 11, 12, 13
img = torch.randn(N, H, W, C)
aud = torch.randn(N, C)

ans = torch.empty(N, H, W)
for batches in range(img.shape[0]):
    for i in range(img.shape[1]):
        for j in range(img.shape[2]):
            ans[batches][i][j] = torch.dot(img[batches][i][j], aud[batches])

ans2 = torch.einsum('nhwc,nc->nhw', img, aud)

assert torch.allclose(ans, ans2, atol=1e-6)
```

Note I had to increase the assertion tolerance above the standard `1e-8` because of numerical precision issues. If `einsum` becomes a bottleneck in more advanced usecases have a look at [opt_einsum](https://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which optimizes the order of underlying operations for performance.